# Question on integrating docker with keycloak and a mariadb backend

Tags: docker, mariadb, keycloak

So i tried building out a docker container for keycloak using a mariadb container as well for the database storage. (I'm really not sure it's worth replacing the database thats built in with keycloak and using mariadb for the server size i'll be using but i wanted to keep it consistant) My question is, has anyone had luck with this? I Can get the container to start (both the keycloak and the mariadb one) Keycloak will initially work and create the required database and tables after connecting to the mariadb server. From what i can tell it's an encoding / coalition issue with keycloak and mariadb. The logs really only throw a lot of errors resembline

```
[Failed SQL: (1194) ALTER TABLE keycloak.CLIENT_SESSION ADD REALM_ID VARCHAR(255) NULL]
```

and the container gets stuck in a restart loop.
Now if i mix it up and configure it with a postgres container, it works fine.

This was the compose settings i was trying to get working.

```
  keycloak_mariadb_production:
    container_name: keycloak_mariadb_production
    image: mariadb:10.7.7-focal
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 33306:3306
    expose:
      - 33306
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_PRODUCTION}"
      MYSQL_USER: "${KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_SU_USERNAME}"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_SU_PASSWORD}"
    command: --init-file /data/application/init.sql
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-keycloak-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./backend/app/init_keycloak.sql:/data/application/init.sql
    healthcheck:
      test: "mysql -u${KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_SU_USERNAME} -p${KEYCLOAK_DATABASE_SU_PASSWORD} -e 'SHOW DATABASES'"
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 20
    networks:
      keycloak_mariadb_production_network:
        aliases:
          - keycloak_mariadb_production_network

  keycloak_frontend_production:
    container_name: keycloak_frontend_production
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.3
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    expose:
      - 8080
    command: ["start-dev"]
    environment:
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
      KC_DB: mariadb
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:mariadb://keycloak_mariadb_production:3306/su_keycloak_production
      KC_DB_USERNAME: "root"
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: "test"
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: Pa55w0rd
    depends_on:
      - keycloak_mariadb_production
    networks:
      - keycloak_mariadb_production_network

networks:
  keycloak_mariadb_production_network:
    driver: bridge
```

I'm just really trying to keep it consistant and keep what i can in a mariadb database. If i have to go the postgress way due to some limitation i can. But i wanted to pick the brains of anyone better than me at this and see if there's been a reliable solution as i have been reading it could be an issue with the jdbc mariadb connector somehow.
Thanks in advance for any advice.

EDIT:

So i tried a base configuration that excluded a local volume under the volumes: stanza, And it boots up fine. It seems like it's not playing well with the local file system if i'm guessing correctly.

```
  mysql:
    image: docker.io/mariadb:10
    environment:
      MARIADB_DATABASE: keycloak
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: password
      MARIADB_USER: keycloak
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0
    environment:
      KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KC_HOSTNAME_PORT: 8080
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_BACKCHANNEL: "true"
      KC_DB: mariadb
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:mariadb://mysql:3306/keycloak?characterEncoding=UTF-8
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: adminpassword
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: "true"
      KC_LOG_LEVEL: info
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8080/health/ready" ]
      interval: 15s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 15
    command: start-dev
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

EDIT To add more logs after attempting to change the permissions of the mysql folder.

```
Updating the configuration and installing your custom providers, if any. Please wait.
2023-02-03 20:03:51,600 INFO  [io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor] (main) Quarkus augmentation completed in 8475ms
2023-02-03 20:03:53,867 INFO  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.hostname.DefaultHostnameProvider] (main) Hostname settings: Base URL: <unset>, Hostname: localhost, Strict HTTPS: false, Path: <request>, Strict BackChannel: true, Admin URL: <unset>, Admin: <request>, Port: 8080, Proxied: false
2023-02-03 20:03:55,742 WARN  [io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.DataSources] (main) Datasource <default> enables XA but transaction recovery is not enabled. Please enable transaction recovery by setting quarkus.transaction-manager.enable-recovery=true, otherwise data may be lost if the application is terminated abruptly
2023-02-03 20:03:57,062 INFO  [org.keycloak.broker.provider.AbstractIdentityProviderMapper] (main) Registering class org.keycloak.broker.provider.mappersync.ConfigSyncEventListener
2023-02-03 20:03:57,150 WARN  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000569: Unable to persist Infinispan internal caches as no global state enabled
2023-02-03 20:03:57,174 WARN  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000554: jboss-marshalling is deprecated and planned for removal
2023-02-03 20:03:57,186 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.infinispan.jboss.marshalling.core.JBossUserMarshaller'
2023-02-03 20:03:57,426 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Triskaidekaphobia' 13.0.10.Final
2023-02-03 20:03:57,948 INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.infinispan.DefaultInfinispanConnectionProviderFactory] (main) Node name: node_251187, Site name: null
2023-02-03 20:03:57,966 WARN  [org.mariadb.jdbc.message.server.ErrorPacket] (main) Error: 1146-42S02: Table 'keycloak.migration_model' doesn't exist
2023-02-03 20:03:58,756 WARN  [org.mariadb.jdbc.message.server.ErrorPacket] (main) Error: 1146-42S02: Table 'keycloak.databasechangelog' doesn't exist
2023-02-03 20:03:59,371 WARN  [org.mariadb.jdbc.message.server.ErrorPacket] (main) Error: 1146-42S02: Table 'keycloak.databasechangeloglock' doesn't exist
2023-02-03 20:03:59,442 WARN  [org.mariadb.jdbc.message.server.ErrorPacket] (main) Error: 1146-42S02: Table 'keycloak.databasechangelog' doesn't exist
2023-02-03 20:03:59,443 INFO  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.storage.legacy.liquibase.QuarkusJpaUpdaterProvider] (main) Initializing database schema. Using changelog META-INF/jpa-changelog-master.xml
2023-02-03 20:04:02,225 WARN  [org.mariadb.jdbc.message.server.ErrorPacket] (main) Error: 1194-HY000: Table 'client_session' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2023-02-03 20:04:02,433 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (development) mode
2023-02-03 20:04:02,434 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to update database
2023-02-03 20:04:02,434 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set META-INF/jpa-changelog-1.1.0.Beta1.xml::1.1.0.Beta1::sthorger@redhat.com:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: (conn=5) Table 'client_session' is marked as crashed and should be repaired [Failed SQL: (1194) ALTER TABLE keycloak.CLIENT_SESSION ADD REALM_ID VARCHAR(255) NULL]
2023-02-03 20:04:02,434 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Migration failed for change set META-INF/jpa-changelog-1.1.0.Beta1.xml::1.1.0.Beta1::sthorger@redhat.com:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: (conn=5) Table 'client_session' is marked as crashed and should be repaired [Failed SQL: (1194) ALTER TABLE keycloak.CLIENT_SESSION ADD REALM_ID VARCHAR(255) NULL]
2023-02-03 20:04:02,434 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: (conn=5) Table 'client_session' is marked as crashed and should be repaired [Failed SQL: (1194) ALTER TABLE keycloak.CLIENT_SESSION ADD REALM_ID VARCHAR(255) NULL]
2023-02-03 20:04:02,434 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: (conn=5) Table 'client_session' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2023-02-03 20:04:02,434 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) For more details run the same command passing the '--verbose' option. Also you can use '--help' to see the details about the usage of the particular command.
2023-02-03 20:05:24,940 INFO  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.hostname.DefaultHostnameProvider] (main) Hostname settings: Base URL: <unset>, Hostname: localhost, Strict HTTPS: false, Path: <request>, Strict BackChannel: true, Admin URL: <unset>, Admin: <request>, Port: 8080, Proxied: false
2023-02-03 20:05:26,529 WARN  [io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.DataSources] (main) Datasource <default> enables XA but transaction recovery is not enabled. Please enable transaction recovery by setting quarkus.transaction-manager.enable-recovery=true, otherwise data may be lost if the application is terminated abruptly
2023-02-03 20:05:27,490 WARN  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000554: jboss-marshalling is deprecated and planned for removal
2023-02-03 20:05:27,555 INFO  [org.keycloak.broker.provider.AbstractIdentityProviderMapper] (main) Registering class org.keycloak.broker.provider.mappersync.ConfigSyncEventListener
2023-02-03 20:05:27,622 WARN  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000569: Unable to persist Infinispan internal caches as no global state enabled
2023-02-03 20:05:27,648 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.infinispan.jboss.marshalling.core.JBossUserMarshaller'
2023-02-03 20:05:27,872 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Triskaidekaphobia' 13.0.10.Final
2023-02-03 20:05:28,399 INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.infinispan.DefaultInfinispanConnectionProviderFactory] (main) Node name: node_228690, Site name: null
2023-02-03 20:05:28,413 WARN  [org.mariadb.jdbc.message.server.ErrorPacket] (main) Error: 1146-42S02: Table 'keycloak.migration_model' doesn't exist
2023-02-03 20:05:29,787 INFO  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.storage.legacy.liquibase.QuarkusJpaUpdaterProvider] (main) Updating database. Using changelog META-INF/jpa-changelog-master.xml
2023-02-03 20:05:30,379 WARN  [org.mariadb.jdbc.message.server.ErrorPacket] (main) Error: 1877-HY000: Table keycloak/client_session is corrupted. Please drop the table and recreate.
2023-02-03 20:05:30,596 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (development) mode
2023-02-03 20:05:30,597 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to update database
2023-02-03 20:05:30,597 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set META-INF/jpa-changelog-1.1.0.Beta1.xml::1.1.0.Beta1::sthorger@redhat.com:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: (conn=25) Table keycloak/client_session is corrupted. Please drop the table and recreate. [Failed SQL: (1877) DELETE FROM keycloak.CLIENT_SESSION]
2023-02-03 20:05:30,597 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Migration failed for change set META-INF/jpa-changelog-1.1.0.Beta1.xml::1.1.0.Beta1::sthorger@redhat.com:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: (conn=25) Table keycloak/client_session is corrupted. Please drop the table and recreate. [Failed SQL: (1877) DELETE FROM keycloak.CLIENT_SESSION]
2023-02-03 20:05:30,597 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: (conn=25) Table keycloak/client_session is corrupted. Please drop the table and recreate. [Failed SQL: (1877) DELETE FROM keycloak.CLIENT_SESSION]
2023-02-03 20:05:30,597 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: (conn=25) Table keycloak/client_session is corrupted. Please drop the table and recreate.
2023-02-03 20:05:30,597 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) For more details run the same command passing the '--verbose' option. Also you can use '--
```

Mariadb container logs

```
2023-02-03 21:43:50 5 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table keycloak/user_entity contains 2 indexes inside InnoDB, which is different from the number of indexes 1 defined in the .frm file. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-troubleshooting/

2023-02-03 21:43:50 5 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table keycloak/user_entity contains 2 indexes inside InnoDB, which is different from the number of indexes 2 defined in the .frm file. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-troubleshooting/

2023-02-03 21:43:51 5 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table keycloak/keycloak_role contains 2 indexes inside InnoDB, which is different from the number of indexes 1 defined in the .frm file. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-troubleshooting/

2023-02-03 21:43:51 5 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table keycloak/client contains 2 indexes inside InnoDB, which is different from the number of indexes 1 defined in the .frm file. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-troubleshooting/

2023-02-03 21:43:51 5 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table keycloak/realm contains 2 indexes inside InnoDB, which is different from the number of indexes 1 defined in the .frm file. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-troubleshooting/
```

Comment: Clean mariadb volume. Why you need custom `init_keycloak.sql`?

Comment: Forgot to remove that, It's a blank file. I Was using it to pre configure some other tables while i was trying to combine databases. I can get it working without a volume now for storage. It seems like it thinks the tables are corrupted while trying to read from the database files when they're stored on the local file system as opposed to being stored in a docker volume.

Comment: Passes initialization scripts via a volume path `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. "tables are corrupted" - why? "Failed SQL: (1194)..." what is using those? Is there more to the error message? "not playing well with the local file system" - how did you determine this?

Comment: Thats the odd part. So, on the initial fire up of the containers, it works, Connects to the database, builds the database and associated tables. Then it re tries connecting to it and reading the tables and throws a lot of "Table 'client_session' is marked as crashed and should be repaired [Failed SQL: (1194)" messages. When i remove the volumes config and it writes to a docker volume it works great. So i'm thinking it's something to do with how it's writing to the local file system. But i'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a permission problem with your volume. Try `chmod 777 ./mysql-keycloak-data` and if it works then use mininal permission for that folder.

Comment: Added some more logs when i tried changing that. Still gives me the same issues it seems.

Comment: @Rob check mariadb logs, not only a keycloak logs

Comment: So looking at them it seems like it's complaining about indexing issues on the tables the keycloak container creates.

Comment: Its really looking like it's not keeping the "DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci" settings if i try and specify them in the compose file. I was comparring the working create table syntax to see what was different from the broken one. Thinking i need to find the right way to set it on the compose file so it sticks.

Comment: So setting the database to a hard coded carset and collate setting it still comes up with the same error. This is kind of an interesting problem. If anyone else has any suggestions i'm definitely open to try.